# $_POST not populating array

Tags: arrays, forms, post

I am working in WordPress and I have a form that a user submits a pin and then next page populates with their name and nearest store location. I am trying to use that information to populate a second form so that they can add their email for alerts.

Here is the code for page one:

```
 <h1>Enter PIN</h1><form method="post" action="/form2">
<input name="PIN" type="text" size="5" maxlength="8" class="input-lg">&nbsp;</p>
<input type="submit" name="btn" class="btn-style" value="submit" /></form> <h5> Please enter PIN EXACTLY as it appears on your letter.`:
```

Here is the second page:

```
global $wpdb; 
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM XXX LEFT JOIN XXX ON XXXX.XXX=XXX.XXX WHERE `PIN` LIKE '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['pin']) . "';";
                  $posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);              
 foreach ($posts as $post)
                {
  print('Hello');
 print('&nbsp;');
       print(' <strong>'.$post->First.' '.$post->Last.'! ' );
                     print('</strong> ');
print('<br>');
            print('Thank you for your interest. To complete your application, please   confirm your email in the boxes below.');
                }

<form method="post" action="form_insert.php" data-parsley-validate>
<input type="hidden" name="PIN"  value="<?php echo $_POST['PIN']?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="First"  value="<?php echo $_POST['First'] ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Middle" value="<?php echo $_POST['Middle'] ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Last"  value="<?php echo $_POST['Last'] ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Title"  value="<?php echo $_POST['Title'] ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Address" value="<?php echo $_POST['Address'] ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Address2"  value="<?php echo $_POST['Address2'] ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="City"  value="<?php echo $_POST['City'] ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="State" value="<?php echo $_POST['State'] ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Zip" value="<?php echo $_POST['Zip'] ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Location"  value="<?php echo $_POST['Location'] ?>"/>
<p><b>Enter Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b> <input  name="Email"  size="26" maxlength="50"      data-parsley-type="email" required >
<br>
<b>Confirm Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b> <input name="emailconf"   size="24" maxlength="50" required data-type="email" >&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" ></p>
</form>
```

All I am getting is empty arrays upon submission to the insert page... I need to carry over the information from the 2 tables and add the email from the form. The email info is submitting to the database. I just need to figure out how to get the other info to the database. As far as injection protection, I just did not include that here

I know I am doing something wrong or forgetting to do something. I am still learning how to code in Wordpress.. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The first page only has `PIN`. Where are all the other values supposed to come from?

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` instead of `=` when you're doing an exact match of the PIN?

Comment: I would believe its a problem with the forms action="/form2". try action=""

Comment: @Barmar. Thank you. I am able to print out all of the fields from the database so I am trying to figure out to get the data that I can print out into the form. Not sure why I did LIKE. Senior moment :)

Comment: Maybe `$_POST['Address']` should be `$posts->Address` and so on?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I went a different route and was able to get it headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you noticed that you have

name="PIN"
in html and

```
$_POST['pin']
```

in php? As I know they must be precisely the same(case sensitive).

Comment: I did notice that and I had fixed it previous without success.. I will try again. Thanks!